# Persisting events for a period of time with React / Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have an app I'm working on with React/Redux. It involves autosaving an entity to a datastore via api as values are changed.

I want to present the user with a "loading" indicator while the entity is being saved and then indicate "Saved!" or some other message once the response comes back from the api and updates the entity's state.

I actually have this working just fine. My reducers are

```
case "UPDATE_ROUND_REQUEST":
    newState = {...state};
    newState[action.meta.id].isSaving = true;
    return newState;

case "UPDATE_ROUND":
    newState = {...state};
    newState[action.meta.id] = action.payload; // This response doesn't have the isSaving prop set
    return newState;
```

And my component props receive this entity and the component accesses the `isSaving` property to display the "saving" message I want

The only problem is that my api returns data in something like 50ms. Basically instant, instant enough that this message is never seen. From a UX perspective what I would like is for my component, when it detects via props that the entity is in the process of loading, to display the saving message for a reasonable period of time so that the user is confident that the data is saved.

I'm struggling with handling that in some sort of stateless way.

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would love to hear other answers on this because it's something I think about as well. Here is one solution that I believe can work. There may be a more performant solution out there though, and it might not be preferable to delay the response from a reducer artificially like I do in my example.

1. Inside of the initial dispatch of the action, you will save the current time as a date object.
2. When the response is received, check to see how long it has been since the request was made.
3. If it has been **x** amount of milliseconds since the request was made, then return the updated state immediately.
4. If it has not been **x** amount of milliseconds, set a timeout with the difference between how long you want the loader to stay at minimum, minus the amount of time that has elapsed since the request was made.

The code below is untested but I believe conceptually it will work.

```
import moment from 'moment';

const round = (
  state = [],
  action,
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_ROUND_REQUEST":
      const newState = {...state};
      newState[action.meta.id].isSaving= true;
      newState[action.meta.id].requestTime= moment(new Date());
      return newState;
    case "UPDATE_ROUND":
      // get difference between now and when the request was sent.
      const difference =  moment(new Date).diff(state[action.meta.id].requestTime);
      const newState = {...state};
      // reset isSaving to false, and changes requestTime back null (default)
      newState[action.meta.id] = {...action.payload, isSaving: false, requestTime: null};
      // if difference is greater than 3 seconds, return the new state immediately.
      if (difference > 3000) {
        // return new state with updated data for the value at newState[action.meta.id].
        return newState;
      }
      // else, if the difference is less than 3 seconds (3000ms), wait the difference and then return the new state
      setTimeout(() => {
        return newState;
      }, 3000 - difference);
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I think this is a pretty good way of executing this. I'd swap out using `moment` for a small function in a helper file. In regards to whether this is a good user experience, I'm torn. I don't know that I really like the idea of making a user wait just for a spinner to show.

Comment: It's pretty well established that interactions seemingly occuring too quickly is a negative user experience. However the real issue is that in my circumstance, it's auto save. The user isn't waiting for anything. I just want the user to know the content is saved. When an indicator never switches between "saving" and "saved" states, and there is no button to save, how can you know your content has saved.

https://uxmag.com/articles/let-your-users-wait | 

https://nexibeo.com/blog/one-of-facebooks-secrets-make-your-users-wait/

Comment: I agree @patrick, if this is the only thing you use moment for, its probably overkill and a small utility function would suffice. I generally use moment in other parts of my application so it doesn't really cost any overhead. Regarding the UI, I've heard arguments for both sides, and ultimately I think it depends on the use case and what the user or project owner prefers. I can see that it might not be necessary in some instances, but in something like a splash screen, it could be nice to have.

Comment: Fair point @YoWakita. Thanks for the links Jared. In regards to autosave, google docs does it well. They have a 'muted' text which toggles between `saving...` and `saved`. This way there's no need for a spinner. Could be worth exploring?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to do the same thing, but here is the crux of the issue...

Even if it was a muted text, react doesn't have time to render an intermediate state. Once redux dispatches the first "REQUEST" action, before  the component has even re-rendered, the "UPDATE" action has already been dispatched, and the component views the entity as never having been in any sort of intermediate state, so my message would always be "saved" because the component never has the time to view any other state.

Comment: Interestingly, I researched google docs a bit. They do a similar thing. If you inspect the XHR requests, they finish quite quickly and the "saving..." message persists for a good second or more after that point.

Comment: Another way that this could be done is rather than having all of the data held up in the reducer after the call, create a connected wrapper component for the loader which does the calculation of the states first request time and the response's received time. That way it does not block the data flow to the store. I'll try to whip up an example of what I am thinking today.